# How would I create a simple batch movement simulator without command prompt closing?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a simple level in a batch game. I know batch isn't ideal for making games and is very limited in its functionality but I still want to challenge myself and try this anyway. The idea for this level is a movement simulation in a corridor with only left and right movement available and I have followed lots of instructions and can't seem to make it work.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
echo off
set "location=#@                /"
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the door.
echo ###################
echo %location%
echo ###################
goto :movement

:movement
choice /c ad /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto :left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto :right
goto :movement

:left
if pos==1 set /a pos=1
if pos<1 set /a pos-=1
goto :position

:right
if pos==17 goto :endlevel
if pos>18 set /a pos+=1
goto :position

:position
if pos=1 set "location=#@                |"
if pos=2 set "location=# @               |"
if pos=3 set "location=#  @              |"
if pos=4 set "location=#   @             |"
if pos=5 set "location=#    @            |"
if pos=6 set "location=#     @           |"
if pos=7 set "location=#      @          |"
if pos=8 set "location=#       @         |"
if pos=9 set "location=#        @        |"
if pos=10 set "location=#         @       |"
if pos=11 set "location=#          @      |"
if pos=12 set "location=#           @     |"
if pos=13 set "location=#            @    |"
if pos=14 set "location=#             @   |"
if pos=15 set "location=#              @  |"
if pos=16 set "location=#               @ |"
if pos=17 set "location=#                @|"
if pos=18 set "location=#                 /"
goto :print

:print
cls
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the     door.
echo ###################
echo %location%
echo ###################
goto :movement

:endlevel
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the door.
echo ###################
echo #                 /
echo ###################
>nul timeout 2
echo That's quite some skills you have.
pause
cls
goto :end

:end
echo woo.
pause
```

For some reason after the first part where it prints the map, if I press either a or d, the command prompt just closes with a message that appears too quickly to read. Could someone point out to me what it is I have done wrong? I'm sure I have just made some kind of simple mistake sorry to be a pain, I'm reasonably new to batch.

Answer (score 1):

First, I ran your code with `echo on` from an already open command prompt, and I got the error messages (or else I would have had a hard time figuring out all the problems).

Your syntax problems:

1. `if pos<1` should be `if %pos% lss 1` (else `pos` is not evaluated, and `<` is input redirection... Actually it should be `gtr` or else it does not work (same thing goes for `if pos>17`)
2. `if pos=1` should be `if %pos% EQU 1`
3. you have to escape the `|` chars with `^`

Here's the code I fixed. It now moves the character. Good luck for your game.

```
@echo off
set/a pos=1
set "location=#@                /"
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the door.
echo ###################
echo %location%
echo ###################
goto movement

:movement
choice /c ad /n
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto left
if %errorlevel% equ 2 goto right
goto movement

:left
if %pos% gtr 1 set /a pos-=1
goto position

:right
if %pos% EQU 17 goto endlevel
if %pos% lss 18 set /a pos+=1
goto position

:position
if %pos% EQU 1 set "location=#@                ^|"
if %pos% EQU 2 set "location=# @               ^|"
if %pos% EQU 3 set "location=#  @              ^|"
if %pos% EQU 4 set "location=#   @             ^|"
if %pos% EQU 5 set "location=#    @            ^|"
if %pos% EQU 6 set "location=#     @           ^|"
if %pos% EQU 7 set "location=#      @          ^|"
if %pos% EQU 8 set "location=#       @         ^|"
if %pos% EQU 9 set "location=#        @        ^|"
if %pos% EQU 10 set "location=#         @       ^|"
if %pos% EQU 11 set "location=#          @      ^|"
if %pos% EQU 12 set "location=#           @     ^|"
if %pos% EQU 13 set "location=#            @    ^|"
if %pos% EQU 14 set "location=#             @   ^|"
if %pos% EQU 15 set "location=#              @  ^|"
if %pos% EQU 16 set "location=#               @ ^|"
if %pos% EQU 17 set "location=#                @^|"
if %pos% EQU 18 set "location=#                 /"
goto print

:print
cls
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the     door.
echo ###################
echo %location%
echo ###################
goto movement

:endlevel
cls
echo Move with a and d. @ is you. You is @. Get to the door. I repeat, the door.
echo ###################
echo #                 /
echo ###################
>nul timeout 2
echo That's quite some skills you have.
pause
cls
goto end

:end
echo woo.
pause
```

Comment: `goto Label` and `goto :Label` are totally equivalent.

Comment: I ignored that. Edited. Thx

Comment: Thanks! this really helps I'll test this again I appreciate the help

Comment: I tried this, and was still recieving errors, I then made some changes myself to try and figure out what the problem was and after changing the if errorlevel statement to if %errorlevel%==1 and the same with 2, it worked perfectly. I also set the pos variable to one at the very start. This seemed to work and it now works fine.